# Retrieve Image from Amazon S3 with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

i am having a problem with retrieving the image from S3.
I have created Upload, Update images functions, But when I want to get Image, it is not working properly.

```
{
    "error": "Something went wrong",
    "msg": {
        "name": "NoSuchKey",
        "$fault": "client",
        "$metadata": {
            "httpStatusCode": 404,
            "requestId": "1NF27DK32TKD7BAT",
            "extendedRequestId": "9WTI/p3Mw0TYh1StlE51Ele60Ks0uL/hHe57zK9tYzwp7ayLZkbwxn9qNOydlywPy3ylHsB7Zgg=",
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        },
        "Code": "NoSuchKey",
        "Key": "avatar-1694252502899.png",
        "RequestId": "1NF27DK32TKD7BAT",
        "HostId": "9WTI/p3Mw0TYh1StlE51Ele60Ks0uL/hHe57zK9tYzwp7ayLZkbwxn9qNOydlywPy3ylHsB7Zgg=",
        "message": "The specified key does not exist."
    } }
```

and here is my GetImage function code:

```
> const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
> const { Users } = require("../../models/users");
> require("dotenv/config");
> 
> const s3 = new S3Client({   region: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_REGION, 
> credentials: {
>     accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY,
>     secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,   }, });
> 
> const getAvatar = async (req, res) => {   try {
>     if (!req.user) {
>       return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized!" });
>     }
>     const userId = req.user.userId;
>     console.log(userId);
>     // Retrieve the user's avatar location from the database
>     const user = await Users.findById(userId);
>     console.log(user);
>     if (!user || !user.avatar) {
>       return res.status(404).json({ error: "Avatar not found" });
>     }
> 
>     // Define the S3 parameters to get the avatar image
>     const params = {
>       Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
>       Key: user.avatar.substring(user.avatar.lastIndexOf("/") + 1), // Extract the filename from the S3 URL
>     };
> 
>     const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand(params);
> 
>     // Fetch the avatar image from S3
>     const { Body } = await s3.send(getObjectCommand);
> 
>     // Determine the content type based on the file extension
>     const fileExtension = params.Key.split(".").pop();
>     let contentType = "image/jpeg"; // Default content type
> 
>     // Adjust the content type based on the file extension
>     if (fileExtension === "png") {
>       contentType = "image/png";
>     } else if (fileExtension === "gif") {
>       contentType = "image/gif";
>     }
> 
>     // Set the appropriate content type for the response
>     res.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
> 
>     // Send the avatar image as the response
>     return res.send(Body);   } catch (error) {
>     return res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong", msg: error });   } };
> 
> module.exports = {   getAvatar, };
```

I have tried different ways, but it didn't work.
here is how I upload the image:

```
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
const { Users } = require("../../models/users");
require("dotenv/config");

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
});

// Define the file filter to accept image formats (you can adjust this based on your allowed formats)
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const allowedMimeTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"];

  if (allowedMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(
      new Error(
        "Invalid file format. Only images (jpeg, png, gif) are allowed."
      )
    );
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      const fileExtension = file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
      cb(null, "Users-avatar/" + `avatar-${Date.now()}.${fileExtension}`);
    },
  }),
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
}).single("avatar"); // Use "avatar" as the field name for avatar uploads

const uploadAvatar = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized User!" });
    }

    upload(req, res, async (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
      }

      // Update the user's avatar field with the S3 file location
      const UserId = req.user.userId;
      const avatarLocation = req.file.location;

      await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(UserId, { avatar: avatarLocation });

      return res.json({ avatar: avatarLocation });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  uploadAvatar,
};
```

So, please help me. Even ChatGPT couldn't solve this issue.